# Getting error 'Creating function "function-1" failed. Error: Request failed with unknown error' while creating google function from console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

While creating google function I am getting the following error:

> Creating function "function-1" failed. Error: Request failed with
> unknown error

I have followed a very simple step from [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python)

I am using app engine default service account for creating google function

Comment: For console errors that are not helpful, you'll probably have contact Google Cloud support directly.  Since there's no code here, there's not much we can do on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have tried with gcloud command and getting timeout.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue you're experiencing. If you have a [support package](https://cloud.google.com/support/) it would be better to file a case to the GCP technical support as Doug Stevenson advised.